# Facebook Auth Dialog: Developer warning concerning the use of "display" type "popup"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

starting today we receive developer warnings in the auth dialog with the following message:

> You are using a display type of 'popup' in a large browser window or tab. For a better user experience, show this dialog with our JavaScript SDK without specifying an explicit display type. The SDK will choose the best display type for each environment. Alternatively, set height and width on your window.open() call to properly size this dialog if you have special requirements precluding you from using the SDK. This message is only visible to developers of your application.

[image: the mentioned warning directly in the popup]

We have the following situation:

- with javascript we open a new popup
- the src of the popup is set with Facebook's PHP-SDK method getLoginUrl
- popup itself has a size of 400px by 580px

The [PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L570) itself references the proper use of "display=popup" within it's own code:

> If you are using the generated URL with a window.open() call in JavaScript, you can pass in display=popup as part of the $params.

The [JS-SDK documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/) says, that the maximum-size of the opened popup should be 400x580:

> For use in a browser popup no bigger than 400px by 580px. Use this display type to maintain context for the user without needing to perform a full-page redirect.

So, to sum up: According to the docs, the implementation above should be ok. Is anyone else having this warning or a solution for this?

Comment: _“popup itself has a size of 400px by 580px”_ – your screenshot suggests otherwise, it’s 446x630 pixels in size …

Comment: I would try 399x579. Consider that it is a suggestion for the developer, the user won't see the warning. Also, don't rely 100% on documentation, it could be wrong :-/

Comment: There's also [another caveat](https://meta.discourse.org/t/configuring-facebook-login-for-discourse/13394/27?u=cawas) to this. Quoting Jeff there: you'll see this alert **only if you log in using the Facebook credentials of the person who registered this Facebook application**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The JS-SDK documentation says the browser popup should be "no bigger than 400px by 580px". What they don't specify is that they mean 400px tall by 580px wide.

I see the developer warning in my popup auth dialogs that are 275 tall by 875 wide.  I do not see the warning in my popups that are 400 tall by 580 wide.

Your image suggests your popup is 630 high by 446 wide. Too big by any reading of the specification.

Comment: thx for your answer. changed my popup-size to 580x400 and the warning is gone. (indeed, the uploaded pic is 630 by 446 - but only due to a resize, that facebook itself is doing. in my code itself the dimensions were 400x580).

Comment: Yes. how did u changed the popup size?

Comment: @Chris you change the popup size the way you set it in the first place. The documentation in the OP's question also explains how: " show this dialog with [Facebook's] JavaScript SDK without specifying an explicit display type" or "set height and width on your window.open() call to properly size this dialog".

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should switch to FB JS SDK and FB.login() method? It always provides the best user experience.

[image: example]

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: will* become invalid when* the link changes :)