# Facebook Login using PHP SDK - Recommends using Javascript

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I've created a simple skeleton app using the PHP SDK for Facebook. This is how I am creating my Login URL:

`$login_url = $fb->getLoginUrl( array (
    'redirect_uri' => $okay_url,
    'scope'        => 'public_profile',
    'display'      => 'popup'
)`

Whenever I try to authenticate my app using this link, there is a pink notice saying:

> You are using a display type of 'popup' in a large browser window or
>   tab. For a better user experience, show this dialog with our
>   JavaScript SDK without specifying an explicit display type. The SDK
>   will choose the best display type for each environment. Alternatively,
>   set height and width on your window.open() call to properly size this
>   dialog if you have special requirements precluding you from using the
>   SDK. This message is only visible to developers of your application.

If I don't set 'display' => 'popup' in the array, then I get the following notice instead:

> You are using a display type of 'page' in a small browser window or
>   popup. For a better user experience, show this dialog with our
>   JavaScript SDK without specifying an explicit display type. The SDK
>   will choose the best display type for each environment. Alternatively,
>   use display type 'popup' if you have special requirements precluding
>   you from using the SDK. This message is only visible to developers of
>   your application.

I realize these notices are only shown to the developers; however, is there any way to prevent them from appearing when using the PHP SDK? Facebook seems to be pushing the Javascript SDK for handling login.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had also same problem. I got the fix from here: 
[Facebook Auth Dialog: Developer warning concerning the use of "display" type "popup"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542490/facebook-auth-dialog-developer-warning-concerning-the-use-of-display-type-po)

The main thing is you have to change the window.open() with mentioning the width=400, height=580

other thing please mention 'display' => 'popup' in the getLoginUrl()

thanks